# Fourier-motzkin

Tags: c, sorting, valgrind

We are trying to use [*Fourier-Motztkin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination) to solve an equation system, to do that we need to sort our matrix by the last element in each row.

First we want to have all our rows where the last element is positive, then the negative ones and at last the zeros. When we run the program using valgrind we get an error message that says:

> "invalid read of size 4" at the first if condition

Comment: what is `T` ? since that is the only unknown variable. It's a parameter and i don't know what it is initialized to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how you are using `T`, I am assuming that you allocated `rows*cols` ints for a matrix.  So when `i=rows-1` the expression `T[i*cols+cols]` becomes `T[rows*cols]`, which is off the end of your allocated memory.  That expression should be `T[i*cols+cols-1]` to read the last element of the row.  You are actually reading the first element of the next row.